# After updating ubuntu 12.04 ... no boot is detected

Tags: 12.04, updates, boot-repair

I have been using ubuntu 12.04 alongside windows 8 for 6 months. I installed all the updates available and now when I try to boot up, it says no boot found press any key to reboot.I did not see what updates were there. It was more than 300MB.
I have Dell Inspiron 15R laptop which came pre-installed with windows 8.
I tried to use boot-repair with recommended settings, it just stays at "Enabling bootinfo" for more than 45 mins.
And now it also not detecting the battery.

Comment: Just to clarify was it windows that updated or Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

make a [Boot-Repair-Disk](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) cd and run Boot-Repair

Alternatively, boot off your Ubuntu Install CD and run the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

then launch boot-repair